# Calling a Stored Procedure from inside a function a using it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a function called

`openCases` where i am trying to call another stored procedure and use its values, but not sure if i can use it this way, please guide if i am wrong way

can i do this in stored procedure, calling in other stored procedure

```
DECLARE @b int
EXEC dbo.info @id, @b OUTPUT;
SET @Eemail = @b.emailaddress
```

is it correct ?

**Update#1**

```
DECLARE @bTable
        ,@Eemail varchar(max)
EXEC dbo.info @id, @b OUTPUT;
    SET @Eemail = @b.emailaddress
```

got an error:

*Must declare the scalar variable* `@Eemail`

Comment: Integer.emailaddresses you are trying to find. you need to do like set @EmailID = @b, assuming EmailID is type of integer

Comment: i am just trying to use the `info` stored values to be used with setting the values from that stored procedure, its not integer, where you see it as integer

Comment: what i use as declaration, a table ?

Comment: U can. As long as u return a table from your sp

Comment: it returns a information about a user

Comment: tried like this, see #Update 1

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure should return a table including email address like below:

```
BEGIN
   select Id, EmailAddress, ..., from myTable;
END
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
DECLARE @bTable table (Id int,Email varchar(max),...)

EXEC dbo.info @id, bTable  OUTPUT;
SET @Eemail = select Email from @bTable
```

If your @bTable includes multiple rows then you will get an error (subquery returned more than 1 rows). To fix it if it happens, use ID in where clause like: `where Id = @Id`